# calculate MAPE stepwise per month in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to calculate the MAPE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error ) of my predictions in python and I have come across one issue.
Basically I want to compare the MAPE of values of different months to each other. I built the idea of what I want to do in an excel sheet for better understanding ( see screenshots )

I wrote two loops which would do exactly that:

```
#Mape0
for i in range(0,100000):
    ent = {}
    n = 0
    for bv,dv in zip(b[i-6:i], d[i-6:i]):
        n+=abs(1-bv/dv)
        n=n/len(b[i-6:i])
        ent['MAPE0'] = n
        print(n)
        result = result.append(ent, ignore_index=True)

   
#MAPE+1
print("Mape1:")
for i in range(0,100000):
    ent={}
    m = 0
    for bv,dv in zip(b[i-5:i+1], d[i-5:i+1]):
        m+=abs(1-bv/dv)
        m=m/len(b[i-5:i+1])
        ent['MAPE+1'] = m
        result = result.append(ent, ignore_index=True)
        print(m)
```

[image: MAPE]

[image: MAPE2]

So far, so good.
Unfortunately, I am not sure how I would ideally write the results back to a csv or excel sheet in a way that would respect the "shift", as my first calculated result would not correspond to the  first line in the resulting excel sheet. It would have to be written into the 6th line and onward. Is there an option to write results to an excel starting from a certain index? or am I missing something more obvious?

I hope it is somewhat understandable what I'm trying to achieve and I would appreciate any input on that.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the solution I was looking for was way more obvious than I thought :)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Pandas already has a built-in index-shift function.